# Android/Rails Convert GPS Coordinates to Street Address

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gps

So I know there are a couple ways to convert GPS coordinates to a street address.

In Rails, I can use [rubygeocoder](http://rubygeocoder.com/).

In Android, I can use reverse geocoding via [geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html).

I've heard of folks running into issues with hitting quotas when doing this however, and I'm wondering what the best way to do this is if I expect to have far more than 2500 requests/day?

If I do it in my backend server, are there any concerns of hitting a quota? If so, does anyone know of any paid or free solutions that don't have a quota?

It seems like doing it on the Android side is probably the best route, given that each "client" would have a different IP address. But I'm always hesitant about doing things like that on the client as opposed to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use other services like open street maps [Nominatim Reverse Geocoding](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding_.2F_Address_lookup)

Or else you can do some kind of hashing in your server.

Comment: Hadn't seen that before. Appreciate the help, that looks like it could work - so you're thinking do this on the server?

Comment: Yea, or even you can do both. First look at the hash (google map), if nothing is found, go query open street map, and only if the result is not acceptable, go query google maps and store the result back into your hash?

Comment: I like it. I like it a lot! Thanks for your help!